# Active Directory users migration between domains without trust relationship

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, migration

Is there any way to make bulk Active Directory users migration from one domain (**forestA**) to another (**forestB**) without establishing trust? Trust between forests cannot be established since **forestB** already has domain with same name as **forestA**. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have overlapping DNS names or NETBios Names then most migration tools will not work. BinaryTree's SmartAD migrator can likely handle this scenario - I don't believe QMM can, as Jay recommended in another answer.

The BinaryTree tool has some significant warts and is not a great tool, but you're pretty limited with your choices with the overlapping domain names.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to check out a software called Quest Migration Manager. Although, you should know there are limitations when trying to migrate without establishing a trust such as losing SIDhistory.

Comment: Are you sure QMM can migrate resources between environments with the same DNS/NETBIOS names? I did not believe that was possible.